# Find length of sublists for iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

```
intlist = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9],[6,2,6]]
```

`intlist` could be anything based on user input, but the number of elements in each subset is to be the same. I am trying to extract the greatest *even* integer from each sublist into a new list. In this case `[2,6,0,6]` would be returned.

I would like to know how to find the length of a given sublist (in turn the length of each sublist) so that I can iterate over that many elements.

```
for r in range(len(intlist)):
    for c in range(?): #Range here should be length of sublist
        if intlist[r][c] % 2 == 0:
            #if it is even, choose max even value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the sublist? That's just `intlist[r]`. It's not super-Pythonic, but:

```
for r in range(len(intlist)):
    for c in range(len(intlist[r])): #Range here should be length of sublist
        if intlist[r][c] % 2 == 0:
            #if it is even, choose max even value.
```

You can clean that up stepwise. E.g., start by finding the sublist, and not depending so much on indexing.

```
for sublist in intlist:
    for c in range(len(sublist)): #Range here should be length of sublist
        if sublist[c] % 2 == 0:
            #if it is even, choose max even value.
```

Then you can strip out the subindex, if what you need is just the value:

```
for sublist in intlist:
    for value in sublist:
        if value % 2 == 0:
            #if it is even, choose max even value.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rare in Python that using something like `range(len(intlist))` is the best approach, so if ever you find yourself writing that sort of thing it's a sign that there are better ways to do it.

You could do this using traditional nested for loops. Eg,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

intlist = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9],[6,2,6]]

maxlist = []
for sublist in intlist:
    evens = []
    for i in sublist:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(i)
    if evens:
        maxlist.append(max(evens))
    else:
        maxlist.append(0)
print maxlist
```

However, it's neater and more efficient to do it using list comprehensions.

```
print [max([i for i in sublist if i % 2 == 0] or [0]) for sublist in intlist]
```

Or in two stages,

```
evenlist = [[i for i in sublist if i % 2 == 0] for sublist in intlist]
print [max(sublist or [0]) for sublist in evenlist]
```

The `or [0]` stuff provides a default list when a sublist contains no even numbers, otherwise `max` raises `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`.

Personally, I'd be inclined to return `None` if a sublist doesn't contain any even numbers. That way you can distinguish between the case when 0 is actually the highest even number present and the case when there are no even numbers in the list. But I guess what's best in this situation depends on the data that you're processing and what you are ultimately doing with it.